# How to write a convolution filter for Edge detection in FabricJS

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I want to write a convolution filter for edge detection in Fabricjs , but the matrix doesn't work.

Here's the Matrix (Idea taken from http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/sobel.htm):

    `new fabric.Image.filters.Convolute({        // edge detect
        matrix: [[  -1, 0, 1,
               -2, 0, 2,
                -1, 0, 1 ],
                [1, 2, 1,
                 0 ,0 ,0,
                -1, -2, 1 ]]
    })`

heres the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Subhasish2015/f6P3R/62/)

**NOTE:-** You need to click on the image to get the check boxes for image processing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since a native html5 canvas element can be an image for Fabric.Image, you can find [an Edge detection solution for native canvas](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/imagefilters/) and then use that native canvas on a Fabric.Image like this `image:myNativeCanvas`.

**[Addition: added a demo]**

**Here's example code and a demo showing how to:**

- Use a native canvas to apply Sobel Edge Detection to an image and
- Use that native canvas as the image source for a Fabric.Image

[image]

```js
// Attribution: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/imagefilters/

//---------------- Script 'filters.js' ----------------


Filters = {};
Filters.getPixels = function(img) {
  var c,ctx;
  if (img.getContext) {
    c = img;
    try { ctx = c.getContext('2d'); } catch(e) {}
  }
  if (!ctx) {
    c = this.getCanvas(img.width, img.height);
    ctx = c.getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  }
  return ctx.getImageData(0,0,c.width,c.height);
};

Filters.getCanvas = function(w,h) {
  var c = document.createElement('canvas');
  c.width = w;
  c.height = h;
  return c;
};

Filters.filterImage = function(filter, image, var_args) {
  var args = [this.getPixels(image)];
  for (var i=2; i<arguments.length; i++) {
    args.push(arguments[i]);
  }
  return filter.apply(null, args);
};

Filters.grayscale = function(pixels, args) {
  var d = pixels.data;
  for (var i=0; i<d.length; i+=4) {
    var r = d[i];
    var g = d[i+1];
    var b = d[i+2];
    // CIE luminance for the RGB
    var v = 0.2126*r + 0.7152*g + 0.0722*b;
    d[i] = d[i+1] = d[i+2] = v
  }
  return pixels;
};

Filters.brightness = function(pixels, adjustment) {
  var d = pixels.data;
  for (var i=0; i<d.length; i+=4) {
    d[i] += adjustment;
    d[i+1] += adjustment;
    d[i+2] += adjustment;
  }
  return pixels;
};

Filters.threshold = function(pixels, threshold) {
  var d = pixels.data;
  for (var i=0; i<d.length; i+=4) {
    var r = d[i];
    var g = d[i+1];
    var b = d[i+2];
    var v = (0.2126*r + 0.7152*g + 0.0722*b >= threshold) ? 255 : 0;
    d[i] = d[i+1] = d[i+2] = v
  }
  return pixels;
};

Filters.tmpCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
Filters.tmpCtx = Filters.tmpCanvas.getContext('2d');

Filters.createImageData = function(w,h) {
  return this.tmpCtx.createImageData(w,h);
};

Filters.convolute = function(pixels, weights, opaque) {
  var side = Math.round(Math.sqrt(weights.length));
  var halfSide = Math.floor(side/2);

  var src = pixels.data;
  var sw = pixels.width;
  var sh = pixels.height;

  var w = sw;
  var h = sh;
  var output = Filters.createImageData(w, h);
  var dst = output.data;

  var alphaFac = opaque ? 1 : 0;

  for (var y=0; y<h; y++) {
    for (var x=0; x<w; x++) {
      var sy = y;
      var sx = x;
      var dstOff = (y*w+x)*4;
      var r=0, g=0, b=0, a=0;
      for (var cy=0; cy<side; cy++) {
        for (var cx=0; cx<side; cx++) {
          var scy = Math.min(sh-1, Math.max(0, sy + cy - halfSide));
          var scx = Math.min(sw-1, Math.max(0, sx + cx - halfSide));
          var srcOff = (scy*sw+scx)*4;
          var wt = weights[cy*side+cx];
          r += src[srcOff] * wt;
          g += src[srcOff+1] * wt;
          b += src[srcOff+2] * wt;
          a += src[srcOff+3] * wt;
        }
      }
      dst[dstOff] = r;
      dst[dstOff+1] = g;
      dst[dstOff+2] = b;
      dst[dstOff+3] = a + alphaFac*(255-a);
    }
  }
  return output;
};

if (!window.Float32Array)
  Float32Array = Array;

Filters.convoluteFloat32 = function(pixels, weights, opaque) {
  var side = Math.round(Math.sqrt(weights.length));
  var halfSide = Math.floor(side/2);

  var src = pixels.data;
  var sw = pixels.width;
  var sh = pixels.height;

  var w = sw;
  var h = sh;
  var output = {
    width: w, height: h, data: new Float32Array(w*h*4)
  };
  var dst = output.data;

  var alphaFac = opaque ? 1 : 0;

  for (var y=0; y<h; y++) {
    for (var x=0; x<w; x++) {
      var sy = y;
      var sx = x;
      var dstOff = (y*w+x)*4;
      var r=0, g=0, b=0, a=0;
      for (var cy=0; cy<side; cy++) {
        for (var cx=0; cx<side; cx++) {
          var scy = Math.min(sh-1, Math.max(0, sy + cy - halfSide));
          var scx = Math.min(sw-1, Math.max(0, sx + cx - halfSide));
          var srcOff = (scy*sw+scx)*4;
          var wt = weights[cy*side+cx];
          r += src[srcOff] * wt;
          g += src[srcOff+1] * wt;
          b += src[srcOff+2] * wt;
          a += src[srcOff+3] * wt;
        }
      }
      dst[dstOff] = r;
      dst[dstOff+1] = g;
      dst[dstOff+2] = b;
      dst[dstOff+3] = a + alphaFac*(255-a);
    }
  }
  return output;
};
//
function runFilter(id, filter, arg1, arg2, arg3) {
  var c = document.getElementById(id);
  var s = c.previousSibling.style;
  var b = c.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
  if (b.originalText == null) {
    b.originalText = b.textContent;
  }
  if (s.display == 'none') {
    s.display = 'inline';
    c.style.display = 'none';
    b.textContent = b.originalText;
  } else {
    var idata = Filters.filterImage(filter, img, arg1, arg2, arg3);
    c.width = idata.width;
    c.height = idata.height;
    var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
    ctx.putImageData(idata, 0, 0);
    s.display = 'none';
    c.style.display = 'inline';
    b.textContent = 'Restore original image';
  }
}
//
sobel = function() {
  runFilter('sobel', function(px){
    px = Filters.grayscale(px);
    var vertical = Filters.convoluteFloat32(px,
      [-1,-2,-1,
        0, 0, 0,
        1, 2, 1]);
    var horizontal = Filters.convoluteFloat32(px,
      [-1,0,1,
       -2,0,2,
       -1,0,1]);
    var id = Filters.createImageData(vertical.width, vertical.height);
    for (var i=0; i<id.data.length; i+=4) {
      var v = Math.abs(vertical.data[i]);
      id.data[i] = v;
      var h = Math.abs(horizontal.data[i]);
      id.data[i+1] = h
      id.data[i+2] = (v+h)/4;
      id.data[i+3] = 255;
    }
    return id;
  });
}

//---------------- Calling script ---------------- 



// load an image 
var image=new Image();
image.crossOrigin='anonymous';
image.onload=start;
image.src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/74/Boy_and_Turtle.png";
function start(){

  // apply Sobel Edge Detection
  // return ImageData of the filtered canvas
  var grayscale = Filters.filterImage(Filters.grayscale, image);
  var vertical = Filters.convoluteFloat32(grayscale,
                                          [ -1, 0, 1,
                                           -2, 0, 2,
                                           -1, 0, 1 ]);
  var horizontal = Filters.convoluteFloat32(grayscale,
                                            [ -1, -2, -1,
                                             0,  0,  0,
                                             1,  2,  1 ]);
  var final_image = Filters.createImageData(vertical.width, vertical.height);
  for (var i=0; i<final_image.data.length; i+=4){
    // make the vertical gradient red
    var v = Math.abs(vertical.data[i]);
    final_image.data[i] = v;
    // make the horizontal gradient green
    var h = Math.abs(horizontal.data[i]);
    final_image.data[i+1] = h;
    // and mix in some blue for aesthetics
    final_image.data[i+2] = (v+h)/4;
    final_image.data[i+3] = 255; // opaque alpha
  }

  // put the filtered imageData on an in-memory canvas
  var memCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  memCanvas.width=image.width;
  memCanvas.height=image.height;
  memCanvas.getContext('2d').putImageData(final_image,0,0);

  // use the in-memory canvas as an image source for a Fabric.Image
  var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
  var imgElement = document.getElementById('my-image');
  var imgInstance = new fabric.Image(memCanvas,{left:0,top:0});
  canvas.add(imgInstance);
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
canvas, img {border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.5.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<h4>Original Image</h4>
<img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/74/Boy_and_Turtle.png' width="250px" height="232px">
<h4>FabricJS image with Sobel filter applied</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width="798px" height="746px"></canvas>
```

Comment: Can you update the fiddle that I provided above ? I am really not getting the idea of how to do it . Thanks

Comment: Sure. I've added example code to my answer. Good luck with your project!

Comment: Thanks for the answer.