# Sobel Edge detection filter using fabric.js and Fabric.Image.filter objects

Tags: glsl, fabricjs, fragment-shader

I am trying to write a fabric.js Image filter.

I am aware of this question which uses fabric.js, but does not implement the edge detection as an actual image filter: [How to write a convolution filter for Edge detection in FabricJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34745497/how-to-write-a-convolution-filter-for-edge-detection-in-fabricjs)

I tried using that code and the example custom Image filter and came up with this:

```js
fabric.Image.filters.Sobel = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Image.filters.BaseFilter, {

type: 'Sobel',

applyTo2d: function(options) {
  var imageData = options.imageData,
      data = imageData.data, i, len = data.length;

  var vertical = Filters.convoluteFloat32(imageData,
                                          [ -1, 0, 1,
                                            -2, 0, 2,
                                            -1, 0, 1 ]);
  var horizontal = Filters.convoluteFloat32(imageData,
                                            [ -1, -2, -1,
                                               0,  0,  0,
                                               1,  2,  1 ]);
  for (i = 0; i < len; i += 4) {
     var v = Math.abs(vertical.data[i]);
     var h = Math.abs(horizontal.data[i]);
     data[i] = (v+h)/2;
     data[i+1] = (v+h)/2;
     data[i+2] = (v+h)/2;
  }
}
});

fabric.Image.filters.Sobel.fromObject = fabric.Image.filters.BaseFilter.fromObject;
```

(NOTE: the above code relies on Filter.js from [this other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34748244/901889))

Applying that filter did not do anything. I know the logic inside the `applyTo2d` function works because I was able to run the Sobel edge detection on the image before passing it to Fabricjs to load.

My suspicion was that I need to include a `fragmentSource` because my browser is using webGL for the fabricjs filters. I will be honest and say webGL fragment shaders are a little over my head, but I did find [this example shader for Sobel in webGL](https://observablehq.com/@mbostock/sobel-in-webgl).

To add it I entered the following code below `type: 'Sobel'`:

```js
fragmentSource: `
precision highp float;

uniform sampler2D u_image;
uniform float u_size;

void main() {
  vec2 p = gl_FragCoord.xy;
  vec4 p0 = texture2D(u_image, (p + vec2(-1.0, -1.0)) / u_size);
  vec4 p1 = texture2D(u_image, (p + vec2(0.0, -1.0)) / u_size);
  vec4 p2 = texture2D(u_image, (p + vec2(1.0, -1.0)) / u_size);
  vec4 p3 = texture2D(u_image, (p + vec2(-1.0, 0.0)) / u_size);
  vec4 p5 = texture2D(u_image, (p + vec2(1.0, 0.0)) / u_size);
  vec4 p6 = texture2D(u_image, (p + vec2(-1.0, 1.0)) / u_size);
  vec4 p7 = texture2D(u_image, (p + vec2(0.0, 1.0)) / u_size);
  vec4 p8 = texture2D(u_image, (p + vec2(1.0, 1.0)) / u_size);
  vec4 gx = -p0 + p2 - 2.0 * p3 + 2.0 * p5 - p6 + p8;
  vec4 gy = -p0 - 2.0 * p1 - p2 + p6 + 2.0 * p7 + p8;
  gl_FragColor = vec4(
    length(vec2(gx.x, gy.x)),
    length(vec2(gx.y, gy.y)),
    length(vec2(gx.z, gy.z)),
    1.0
  );
}
`,
```

However that just gives me a black image when I apply the filter. At this point I think there are two possible solutions:

1. Figure out how to get the fragmentSource working
2. Figure out how to force fabricjs to not use webGL for this one filter (ideally while continuing to use webGL for all other filters)

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @jminardi fabric offers a composed + convolution filter that is generic enough for sobel too.
You would create a composed filter with 2 convolution filters.

#### Step 1: create the 2 pass of sobel as convolute filters

```
   var sobelVLines = new fabric.Image.filters.Convolute({
     matrix: [ -1, 0, 1,  -2, 0, 2,  -1, 0, 1 ]
   });

   var sobelHLines = new fabric.Image.filters.Convolute({
     matrix: [ -1, -2, -1, 0,  0,  0, 1,  2,  1 ]
   });
```

#### Step 2: reference those 2 filters in the composed subFilters property.

```
fabric.Image.filters.Sobel = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Image.filters.Composed, {

type: 'Sobel',

subFilters: [sobelVLines, sobelHLines],

});

fabric.Image.filters.Sobel.fromObject = fabric.Image.filters.Composed.fromObject;
```

And this could do it i think!

Comment: I did play around with the built it `Convolute` filter and it almost works as I need, but Sobel needs to be the combined output of two separate convolutions. (`[ -1, 0, 1,  -2, 0, 2,  -1, 0, 1 ]` and `[ -1, -2, -1, 0,  0,  0, 1,  2,  1 ]`)

Comment: and that is what the composed filter is there for! i ll update the answer asap

Comment: Check if now is what you want. This is a way to create custom filters starting from more basic one. You can of course write your own custom webgl shader, is a bit more complex, it can save you a texture copy or 2.